# Senocular Path class

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Does anyone have any idea on how to make a counter clockwise circle using Senocular's Path class?

For example, if I start a half-circle on the left (9 o'clock) it will go to 6 o'clock then 3 o'clock. Right now it goes for 9 o'clock to 12 then 3.

Works great clockwise... but I can't get it to draw in the other direction. I tried messing with the math inside the class and it exploded!

Here is a link to his source file:

http://www.senocular.com/flash/actionscript/?file=ActionScript_3.0/com/senocular/drawing/Path.as

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I gave the code a once over and that is about it. Did you try reversing the array right before you draw? Array.reverse() 
Also it looks like you can add the points in any direction you want it doesn't sort them or anything like that.

Just a thought.